# VS 2012 & IIS Express With Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I have successfully setup my development environment on one machine utilizing IIS Express and Windows Authentication to essentially force a web application to use SSL.  When I pulled the code down onto a secondary dev machine, I've run into all kinds of issues.

It appears that the startup URL as defined in the project properties while working on the initial dev machine needed to be resetup on the new machine.  I went into the IIS Express config and made sure that anonymous authentication was disabled and Windows Auth was enabled.  I also added the bindings to essentially replicate what the initial dev machine was setup as.

I then opened the web app in Visual Studio again and this time received no errors or warnings.  I figured no errors meant things would be OK.... Whoops...

The app now appears to load and I'm immediately challenged for my windows credentials.  I enter them, and then get re-challenged.  It appears there is some kind of loop going on here.

#### 1. What am I doing wrong?

#### 2. Shouldn't there be a better way for distributed development and IIS Express (SSL)?

Comment: Are they local machine credentials, domain credentials, etc. can you do a 'run as' at the command line with that same user? Did you manually edit config it allow the VS GUI to control the settings for you?

Comment: The credentials are domain credentials.  When I launch VS, it is as Admin.  I've tried both manually editing the config and letting VS do the magic.  Both have yielded same result.